# MYSQL search table, bit fields

Tags: mysql, bit

I have a table with rows and where one field is a bit-value with 7 digits.

Suppose I have a procedure where I want to select all rows where this bit field equals '0101010', this is easily done by select * where ....  and so on.

But: how do I do if I want to allow one/multiple digits of the digits to be either 1 Or 0, i.e I want to get all rows where the bitfield has an entry on the form 1001*1* where the * can be either 1 or 0. So, in this case I would like all entries where the bit field is  1001010, 1001011, 1001110 or  1001111.

select * from TABLE where bit_field in (1001010, 1001011, 1001110, 1001111) would probably work in this example, but if I want to use only the string '1001*1*' as input to the procedure, what then?
.
Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks,
Niklas

Edit: I've tried this: select * from table where field like bit'\\\0'; for getting all entries of the form ******0, but that didn't work...

Edit2: It turned out it vas a bit-field, not binary... problem still remain though.

Comment: Maybe you could divide this column into 7 separate columns?

Comment: That's my first thought as well... BUT - the problem is I'm not developing this database, just upgrading it. If I want 7 separate columns I need to a) change in the database and 2) look through thousands of lines of php and stored procedures to change how the data is retrieved and stored.... and I don't feel like doing that :-)

Comment: However: I almost got it to work by this command: select cast(BIN(bit_field) as char(7)) from TABLE where  cast(BIN(bit_field) as char(7)) like '_1_1_0_0'; here using _ as "wildcard" for one "bit"

Comment: The problem then is that if the field is zero, when selecting ".... like '_ _ _ _ _ _ 0'; WILL NOT give the bit-field '0000000', since when converting that from bit to string I only get a single '0', which of course doesn't match '0000000'. So: any ideas on how I can get the full '0000000' instead of only one 0 when casting?

Comment: that goes btw for everything that begins with a 0: I always get the string starting at the first non-zero element. So bit 0011111 gives the string 11111, and so on

Comment: Maybe cast it to int with zerofill option and than cast to char? You could also write a trigger which would propagate data to separate columns and use function to search it like you want.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I did this: select LPAD(cast(BIN(bit_field) as char(7)),7,'0') from TABLE where  LPAD(cast(BIN(bit_field) as char(7)),7,'0') like '______0'; and it worked perfect - thanks!

Comment: gah - it worked in the sql-command window, but when putting it into a procedure I got the error "Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'like'".... this drives me crazy!

Comment: Solved it, using COLLATE to get the right collations of the data I compare with each other!

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, per se', but an alternative approach.  You mentioned that you didn't want to convert to individual columns because of legacy code.  If you *do* want individual columns and the only thing holding you back is the legacy code, consider the following.

You could add columns for the options and use insert/update triggers to populate them OR you could create a view that splits the bits into separate columns.  For new development, you can code to the new columns.  Over time, as you modify legacy code you can change it to the new approach.  When all the "read" legacy code has been changed, the last step is to change the "write" code to use the new columns rather than the bit column and remove the triggers.

I have a SQL Fiddle demonstrating this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77a5c/2).  Note that I only included an insert trigger for brevity.